# Difference between mvn button on intellij vs running mvn command via terminal

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Please don't kill me for this question, it looks dumb but it has been bugging me a lot. What's the difference between the mvn button available in IntelliJ on top right compared to running the mvn commands via the integrated terminal? What I have noticed is on running mvn clean install via the button actually broke down my project - mvn commands from terminal stopped working which were working earlier. Vice-versa is also true. My best guess is it's about the environments/versions of mavens which are setup differently : integrated terminal might be picking values from my bash_profile whereas the IntelliJ button picks up configurations based on IntelliJ Preferences but I would really like to hear more thoughts and answers about this.

Comment: Intellij is also adding the settings you can configuring in the maven menu to the command line. e.g. java version, skip tests etc.

Comment: You can see this when you start a build with the maven buttons and scroll to the top to see the command line.

Comment: You can try and run `mvn help:effective-settings` from both and see the results